# How do add multiple knockout function within single viewmodel? And again how can we call this viewmodel to MVC view to run the application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I am writing `CRUD` application using `ASP.NET MVC`, `KnockoutJS` and database. When I write separate `viewmodel` for Create, Read, Update and Delete. and calling each view model in separate view (Create, Read, Update and Delete) then It's working fine. But when I include all view model in one single view model, then calling that view model in every View. Then I am neither able to create nor able to edit.

Please help me with this. I tried so many ways but could not get a proper solution.

I have written this function using `Knockout`:

```
   $(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(modelView);
   });
   Var parsedSelectedCourse = $.parseJSON(selectedCourse);
   var modelView = {
    Read: {
        Courses: ko.observableArray([]),
        viewCourses: function() {
            var thisObj = this;
            try {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/ListCourses',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        thisObj.Courses(data); //Here we are assigning values to KO Observable array
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
                    }
                });
            } catch (e) {
                window.location.href = '/Home/Read/';
            }
        }
    },
    Create: {
        CourseName: ko.observable(),
        CourseDescription: ko.observable(),
        createCourse: function() {
            try {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/Create',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: ko.toJSON(this), //Here the data wil be converted to JSON
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: successCallback,
                    error: errorCallback
                });
            } catch (e) {
                window.location.href = '/Home/Read/';
            }
        }
    },
    Update: {
        CourseID: ko.observable(parsedSelectedCourse.CourseID),
        CourseName: ko.observable(parsedSelectedCourse.CourseName),
        CourseDescription: ko.observable(parsedSelectedCourse.CourseDescription),
        updateCourse: function() {
            try {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/Update',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: ko.toJSON(this),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: successCallback,
                    error: errorCallback
                });
            } catch (e) {
                window.location.href = '/Home/Read/';
            }
        }
    },
    Delete: {
        CourseID: ko.observable(parsedSelectedCourse.CourseID),
        CourseName: ko.observable(parsedSelectedCourse.CourseName),
        CourseDescription: ko.observable(parsedSelectedCourse.CourseDescription),
        deleteCourse: function() {
            try {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/Delete',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: ko.toJSON(this),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: successCallback,
                    error: errorCallback
                });
            } catch (e) {
                window.location.href = '/Home/Read/';
            }
        }
    }
   };

   function successCallback(data) {
    window.location.href = '/Home/Read/';
   }

   function errorCallback(err) {
    window.location.href = '/Home/Read/';
   }
```

Comment: What error are you getting? How do you bind/call to the methods?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "with: function (){return Read }"
Message: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return Courses }"
Message: Courses is not defined

Comment: Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.